# Need to resize browser for footer in popup to appear(Jquery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am testing out the popup in Jquery Mobile, i have this content that popups up when a button is clicked, and in the popup content there is also a footer inside, but the footer won't appear(only when i resize the browser). I am not sure why the footer won't appear. And also i have set the content to be scrollable but it is not scrolling at the moment at all.

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog33" data-overlay-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:100%;" id="popcontent">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content scroll" >
       <input type="text" data-role="date">
    <p>Filter test</p>

        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow">Yes</a>

     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
        <legend>Icon right:</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6a" id="checkbox-h-6a">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6a">test1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6b" id="checkbox-h-6b">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6b">test2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6c" id="checkbox-h-6c">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6c">test3</label>
    </fieldset>

  <a data-role="footer" id="Apply" data-position="fixed"  data-tap-toggle="false">
    <h4>Apply Filter</h4>
</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for scrolling, you need a plugin e.g. iScrollview, iScroll.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bs3gm3e0/?

Comment: Yer like that! Thanks i will give it a go!